# how does boxplot in pandas/python work?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I found this link and I'm trying to understand how boxplot works.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#box-plotting

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))

plt.figure();
bp = df.boxplot()
```

I would expect boxplot to want 4 values for each box however it seems to construct a box for each 10 points and I was wondering what is going on in the background..

The four points i'm referring to are whisker high, low, box high, low

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `DataFrame` (actual numbers may differ because of `rand`):

```
In [13]: df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.199953  0.261683  0.582105  0.969489  0.351161
1  0.424425  0.901810  0.942510  0.985630  0.947160
2  0.809123  0.311318  0.954326  0.022269  0.472182
3  0.685818  0.172807  0.093368  0.406808  0.590702
4  0.590784  0.291439  0.139792  0.243264  0.671586
5  0.215574  0.253957  0.257037  0.895526  0.903883
6  0.469410  0.062405  0.518797  0.706974  0.956250
7  0.320845  0.924984  0.740085  0.939595  0.258833
8  0.058665  0.364624  0.832847  0.790947  0.835429
9  0.924942  0.077599  0.411044  0.075257  0.703015
```

Boxplot creates five boxes corresponding to each column of the `DataFrame`. Each box depicts the median (red line), 25th percentile (lower edge of the box), 75th percentile (upper edge of the box), and the most extreme observations (the whiskers).

Does that make sense?

Comment: about the 25th percentile and 75th percentile, is that done by fitting a normal distribution or ?

Comment: well no I suppose, it should be really just standard percentiles computed from the data... http://onlinestatbook.com/2/introduction/percentiles.html